# How to extract field value from eflags in GDB

Tags: rust, gdb

In gdb x86_64 environment, like below example, when I tried to extract field value of $eflags to use as a breakpoint condition element, I got an error.

```
(gdb) cond 1 ($eflags & 0x200) != 0
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Invalid cast.
[Switching to Thread 1.1]
```

Ofcourse, when extracting a specific field of $eflags, like `p $eflags & 0x200`, I got also `Invalid cast` error.

How to get a specific field from $eflags?

I do not know whether it is related or not, I debug a Rust program.

**Environment**

- uname -a: Linux ubuntuMac 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS
- cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
- gdb version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `p $eflags & 0x200`

This doesn't work because:

```
(gdb) ptype $eflags
type = flag i386_eflags {
    bool CF @0;
    bool @1;
    bool PF @2;
    bool AF @4;
    bool ZF @6;
    bool SF @7;
    bool TF @8;
    bool IF @9;
    bool DF @10;
    bool OF @11;
    bool NT @14;
    bool RF @16;
    bool VM @17;
    bool AC @18;
    bool VIF @19;
    bool VIP @20;
    bool ID @21;
}
```

However, you can cast `$eflags` to `int`:

```
(gdb) p $eflags
$1 = [ IF ]
(gdb) p/x (int)$eflags
$2 = 0x202
(gdb) p/x (int)$eflags & 0x2
$3 = 0x2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Because of Rust environment, I cannot use c style type cast. Instead, using `$eflags as u32` works well!

Comment: Note that using `u64` or `usize` instead of `u32` will cause `invalid cast` error.